# Listing Blocks of content in horizontal line html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make blocks of information presented in horizontal list, and they are currently vertical. Any suggestions?[[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEexs.png)block example][code]

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: display:inline-block;

Comment: where is the code?

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Block 1</li>
  <li>Block 2</li>
  <li>Block 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing what I think you are asking would be to use the CSS "display" property. You just need to set the container of all the blocks you want inline horizontally to "display: inline-block", and then float them.

For example:
HTML:

```
<div id="container">
     <div class="block">
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;
}

.block {
    float: left;
}
```